# Programme crashes upon displaying '&' symbol in wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

I am working with Python v2.7, wxPython v3.0 on a Windows 7 32-bit machine.
In my app I wanted to display the `&` symbol.

**Problem**: My programme crashes immediately if I try to display this particular  `&` symbol. All other symbols can be displayed without any problem.

[image: crash-screenshot]

Here is a **sample code** for playing around:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import wx
class mainClass(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Test v1.0", style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE,size=(400,300))
        mainPanel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        wx.StaticText(mainPanel, -1, u'\x25')# This is '%' symbol
        wx.StaticText(mainPanel, -1, u'\x26')# This is '&' symbol

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = mainClass().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

If you comment out this `wx.StaticText(mainPanel, -1, u'\x26')` the programme works fine.

**Question**: What could be the reason for this? I'll really appreciate if some one can test this on his/her system and report back! Thanks.

Reference to unicode symbols table. http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=0x

Answer (score 1):

This code runs for me on Kubuntu 14.04 64-bit, wxPython 2.8.12 and Python 2.7. Not however that you do not specify the location of the two StaticText widgets, so they just stack on top of each other. You should either specify their position or use sizers.

Also, if all you want to do is display an ampersand ("&"), then you can just do this:

```
import wx
class mainClass(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Test v1.0", style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE,size=(400,300))
        mainPanel = wx.Panel(self, -1)

        wx.StaticText(mainPanel, -1, "&&")# This is '&' symbol

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = mainClass().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

There is no need to use the unicode specification for a regular ASCII character.

Comment: Yes, Your trick worked for me. But still I am wondering why was my programm crashing? Any how I'll select your answer for providing an alternate solution! I 'll just wait for some other users for providing me some hints before I close this question. Thanks Mike.

Comment: I should note that when I use **u'\x26'** and comment out the other one, the code just shows an empty frame.

Comment: If you don't receive any other good answers, you should post your question to the wxPython Google group. They will probably have some useful feedback for you.

Comment: Thanks for testing the script.